# test.c:51:4: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘blk from type ‘void *’

Tags: c, types, struct, void-pointers

```
    typedef struct abc{

        int a;
        char b;

    }abc;

    typedef abc bkl[1];
    .
    .
    .

    blk b;

b=shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); //This error that (Void *) to blk 
                              //But anyway blk is pointer,it isnt ? 

blk *b;
b=shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); //This is correct, why? b pointor to pointer
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't typedef array types. All you get is this kind of problem. And I wouldn't even typedef pointers-to-whatever. Write down all the `*` in the declaration of the variables and it'll be much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
blk b;
```

is the same as:

```
abc b[1];
```

`b` is not a pointer in the sense that you are using it.

```
b = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

is incorrect because you can't assign a pointer to an array. That is wrong exactly the way the following  is wrong.

```
int arr[3];
arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```